# How to set canvas camera position in python 3.7

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, camera

I am writing a mario-like game (non-commercial, I'm just trying to brush up on coding) and I need to follow one of two players. Messing with canvas.move doesn't work for my needs, I was wondering if there was some way to actually control what position it renders from (such as one player offscreen and the camera moves to make him onscreen). My code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import math,time

## Declare your many GAME CLASSES here
class Camera:
    def __init__(self,game):
        self.cnv=game.canvas
        self.tracker=None
    def track(self,player):
        self.tracker=player
    def run(self):
        cords=self.cnv.coords(self.tracker.id)
        self.cnv.move(ALL,250-cords[0],250-cords[1])
class Human:
    def __init__(self,game):
        game.tk.bind_all("<KeyPress>",self.press)
        game.tk.bind_all("<KeyRelease>",self.release)
        self.left=False
        self.right=False
        self.jump=False
    def run(self,player):
        if self.left:
            player.left()
        if self.right:
            player.right()
        if self.jump:
            player.jump()
            self.jump=False
    def press(self,event):
        if event.keysym=="Left":
            self.left=True
        if event.keysym=="Right":
            self.right=True
        if event.keysym=="Up":
            self.jump=True
    def release(self,event):
        if event.keysym=="Left":
            self.left=False
        if event.keysym=="Right":
            self.right=False
    def hitx(self):
        pass
    def hity(self):
        pass
class Computer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.direction=1
    def run(self,player):
        if player.onground:
            if self.direction==1:
                player.right()
            if self.direction==-1:
                player.left()
    def hitx(self):
        self.direction*=-1
    def hity(self):
        pass
class Player:
    def __init__(self,startx,starty,game,controller):
        self.id=game.canvas.create_image(250+startx,250+starty,anchor=CENTER,image=game.player_images[0])
        self.game=game
        self.xv=0
        self.yv=0
        self.controller=controller
        self.speed=4
        self.face=0
        self.side=0
        self.onground=False
    def left(self):
        self.xv-=self.speed
        self.side=1
        self.face=tick%2
    def right(self):
        self.xv+=self.speed
        self.side=0
        self.face=tick%2
    def jump(self):
        if self.onground:
            self.yv=math.sqrt(self.speed)*-10
    def look(self):
        bricks=[]
        for x in self.game.tileset:
            coords=self.game.canvas.coords(x[0])
            playercoords=self.game.canvas.coords(self.id)
            xdifference=abs(coords[0]-playercoords[0])
            ydifference=abs(coords[1]-playercoords[1])
            if xdifference<250 and ydifference<250:
                bricks.append(coords)
    def run_slf(self):
        if not self.onground:
            self.face=2
        self.set_face()
        self.face=0
        self.onground=False
        self.game.canvas.move(self.id,self.xv,0)

        ## Work in progress: Do the X COLLISIONS FOR THE PLAYER
        bounds=self.getbounds()
        if len(self.game.canvas.find_overlapping(*bounds))>1:
            while len(self.game.canvas.find_overlapping(*bounds))>1:
                self.game.canvas.move(self.id,abs(self.xv)/self.xv*-1,0)
                bounds=self.getbounds()
            self.xv=0
            self.controller.hitx()

        self.game.canvas.move(self.id,0,self.yv)
        ## Work in progress: Do the Y COLLISIONS FOR THE PLAYER
        bounds=self.getbounds()
        if len(self.game.canvas.find_overlapping(*bounds))>1:
            while len(self.game.canvas.find_overlapping(*bounds))>1:
                self.game.canvas.move(self.id,0,abs(self.yv)/self.yv*-1)
                bounds=self.getbounds()
            self.yv=0
            self.onground=True
            self.controller.hity()
        self.controller.run(self)
        self.xv*=0.8
        self.yv+=1
    def set_face(self):
        self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.id,image=game.player_images[self.face+(self.side*3)])
    def getbounds(self):
        width=25
        height=45
        cords=self.game.canvas.coords(self.id)
        return [cords[0]-width,cords[1]-height,cords[0]+width,cords[1]+height]
class Game:
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.tileset=[]
        self.players=[]
        self.tk=Tk()
        self.brick_types={"regular":[False,PhotoImage(file="blocks/brick_basic.png")]}
        self.tk.resizable(0,0)
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.tk,width=width,height=height,background="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.player_images=[PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/face.png"),PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/walk.png"),PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/jump.png"),PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/face-2.png"),PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/walk-2.png"),PhotoImage(file="marioAnim/jump-2.png")]
    def run(self):
        self.tk.update_idletasks()
        self.tk.update()
        for x in self.players:
            x.run_slf()
    def addbrick(self,x,y,tp):
        self.tileset.append([self.canvas.create_image(x*50+250,y*50+250,anchor="nw",image=self.brick_types[tp][1]),self.brick_types[tp][0]])
    def addline(self,x,y,xd,yd,length,tp):
        for i in range(0,length):
            self.addbrick(x+xd*i,y+yd*i,tp)
    def addplayer(self,player):
        self.players.append(player)

## Declare your GLOBAL VARIABLES here.
game=Game(500,500)
human=Human(game)
computer=Computer()
cplayer=Player(-50,0,game,computer)
hplayer=Player(50,0,game,human)
tick=0
camera=Camera(game)
camera.track(cplayer)

## BUILD TILESET
game.addline(-8,4,1,0,16,'regular')
game.addbrick(-5,3,'regular')
game.addbrick(4,3,'regular')

## ADD PLAYERS
game.addplayer(cplayer)
game.addplayer(hplayer)
while 1:
    tick+=1
    camera.run()
    game.run()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

I am using python 3.7 with Tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking how to programatically scroll the canvas. The xview and yview methods of the canvas control what portion of the full drawable area is visible at the current time: `xview`, `xview_moveto`, `xview_scroll`, `yview`, `yview_moveto`, and `yview_scroll`.

The `xview_scroll` and `yview_scroll` methods accept an integer amount, and then the string "units" or "pages". "units" refers to the distance defined by the `xscrollincrement` and `yscrollincrement` attributes. "pages" causes the window to scroll in increments of 9/10ths of the window width or height.

For example, if you want to be able to scroll by single pixels you can set `xscrollincrement` to `1`, and the use `xview_scroll` to move left or right.

```
canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=1)
...
canvas.xview_scroll(1, "units")
```

Comment: Does xview_moveto do the same thing?

Comment: @nerdguy: conceptually, yes, but it lets you move the canvas to a specific position. For example, `moveto(.5)` will scroll so that have of the canvas is off screen to the left.

Comment: moveto doesn't work no matter what value i pass to it. I did do the `canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=0)`.

Comment: @nerdguy: you probably need to configure the `scrollregion` attribute.

Comment: I did. It doesn't change anything.